# terraform-provider-local on Windows and Linux (Terraform Cloud Worker VMs)

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

On my Windows machine I have `istioctl.exe` on my PATH.
When I run this `local-exec` it works.

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = "${path.module}/tmp"
    command     = <<EOH
istioctl version --remote=false;
    EOH
  }
```

For Terraform Cloud I first download `istioctl` and place it in `${path.module}/tmp`.
But I need to change the `local-exec` above to `./istioctl version --remote=false;`.

For TFC is there a way to add `istioctl` to the `PATH` so I do not have to use the `./`?